# Ordering widgets in IPython notebooks

Tags: python-2.7, widget, jupyter-notebook

I'm playing with the module widgets of IPython (`IPython.html.widgets`), creating some widgets.

What I am doing is creating a bunch of widgets, let say 4 integer sliders:

```
w1 = widgets.IntSliderWidget(description='w1')
w2 = widgets.IntSliderWidget(description='w2')
w3 = widgets.IntSliderWidget(description='w3')
w4 = widgets.IntSliderWidget(description='w4')
```

and I would like to use the function `interact()` on a function `a_function()`, to play with the widgets. But I am looking to have a code where I do not explicitly list all the widgets in my arguments of the function (something generic). Something like:

```
def a_function(**kwargs):
    print kwargs
    # do other things...

kwargs = {}
kwargs['w1'] = w1
kwargs['w2'] = w2
kwargs['w3'] = w3
kwargs['w4'] = w4

# calling the function interact() to interact with the function a_function()
interact(a_function, **kwargs)
```

My problem is that dictionaries in Python are unsorted but I would like to manage the order the widgets appear in the notebook. I want to be sure that widget `w1` will appear before `w2`, `w2` before `w3`, and so on...

Any suggestion to solve this issue?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to sort the keys:

```
def a_function(**kwargs):
    for k in sorted(kwargs.keys()):
        print k, kwargs[k]
    # do other things...
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using collections.OrderedDict() instead of dict()?  It remembers the order the keys were inserted.